# Levelling deep spots in concrete floor

Tags: concrete, leveling

I have a large room with a corner that goes close to 3" below level.  Rather than dumping bag after bag of SLC, it seems like maybe I should use a regular mortar or concrete to get it up to near level then use SLC to finish off what my hack concrete job will probably look like?

As the dip nears level, what's the minimum thickness I should go if mortar or concrete is advisable?

Comment: not really sure what you're asking? Minimum thickness of concrete is probably 1.5 times the size of the biggest aggregate you put in it in a "workable" sense. I'd aim for a quarter inch below level then finish off with SLC, or maybe just go to level and smooth the concrete off if I was putting tiles or wood over it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 3” I would mix up a batch with turkey grit much larger than sand but smaller than pea gravel. I have used this mix to level garages that had a similar slope to the door when making them a living space.

The existing floor needs to be clean and I would do a heavy etch of muriatic acid and water. After rinsing I would put down an adhesion promoter then start your pour.  I have done this by hand mixer Several times but one case I did get what I needed on a short load , much easier, I did have to wait a few extra days but it was worth it!  only a yard and a half but hand mixing the start is almost set by the time you finish So it takes 3 or that’s how we did it 1 person on the mixer the other two raking & floating. But we did this close to a dozen times to add living space.